# how to stop adafruit-webide service from autostarting

Tags: boot, pi-3, services

After installing adafruit-webide I realized the server autostarts at boot.
I tried to prevent the service from autostarting to no avail

I tried all of these:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f adafruit-webide.sh remove
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/adafruit-webide.sh.override
sudo update-rc.d adafruit-webide.sh disable
```

always

```
sudo service --status-all
```

shows the service running (and I can enter the ide in my browser).

Even

```
sudo service adafruit-webide.sh stop
```

is not stopping the service.

I must be doing something really wrong.
I am running and up-to-date raspbian on a rasbberry pi 3.
I do not want to remove the program I just want to start/stop the service when required.

**EDIT**
I tried `systemd` commands like

> sudo systemctl disable adafruit-webide.service

to no avail. Service is always on after reboot.

And there is something more interesting: when using  `sudo service adafruit-webide stop`, I can see it actually stopping but, after few seconds, it restarts again:

[image: automatic restart after stop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked is marking the service as unstartable with

```
sudo systemctl mask adafruit-webide.service
```

`systemctl stop/disable` did not work for some reason.
`systemctl mask` is a more aggresive mode of stopping the service.
It links the unit to /dev/null making the service un-startable either manually or automatically unless it is unmasked again.

There are interesting references [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-masking-units/), [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-administration-kill.html) (both from fedora) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)